# Will ISP know the location of public comment on Facebook via query link?

Tags: dns, facebook, isp

Let say that a person has made a comment on a Facebook group and in the browser address bar it will have a link with the following format. If someone clicked on this link, it will jump straight to the public comment (this is just a sample link):

```
https://www.facebook.com/groups/402723123456/permalink/137534228296458/?comment_id=137618378287832&reply_comment_id=137641101624443&notif_id=1620042359222561&ref=notif&notif_t=group_comment_mention
```

I have read that ISP can see the person's IP address visited the domain `facebook.com` but will ISP got the full link of the comment link above?

I ask this question because I'm doubt whether I should use VPN to prevent this information leaked to ISP.

Comment: No. Only domain name is visible to them. Query string is encrypted.

Comment: As @default stated: The ISP will only see up to the first slash (/) after the ".com".

Comment: Thanks, the question is similar to the https as suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your connection is HTTPS, meaning it is encrypted, which Facebook is, it's very unlikely they can see the content of your data traffic. They do know what sites you are connecting to however. One of the most important things about this however, is that whatever data you give, is shared, sold, and copied. Facebook is one of the biggest faces in the data market. ISPs also tend to partake. It's not certain, but certainly not impossible, that the data could get back to them.